# MATLAB - copying specific values from one 3d array to another

Tags: arrays, matlab, graphics, vectorization, homography

I need to update image 1 with rgb values from image 2 for specific coordinates.

I have two 2d matrices (im1Cart_toupdate 2x114056 and im2EstCart_tocopyfrom also 2x114056).  These contain the ordered x-y pairs for which I want to copy rgb values from image 2 to image 1.

i.e. there are 114,056 pixels where I want to copy colours across.

im1 (440x1370x3) and im2 (240x320x3) are the image arrays.  Note im2 is going to be stretched, so some pixels from im2 will appear more than once in im2EstCart_tocopyfrom.

I need an efficient way of doing this, as even with the above image sizes my current implementation is very slow.  I had thought that there may be some approach using sub2ind - but am not sure how to do this with 3d arrays.

Here's my current code.  It's the for loop that's killing me!

```
%Create a matrix of all pixel coordinates in im1 (homogenised form)
[im1gridx im1gridy]=meshgrid(1:im1width,1:im1height);
im1Cart = [im1gridx(:) im1gridy(:)]';
im1Hom = [im1Cart; ones(1,numel(im1gridy))];

%transform pixel positions with homography (HEst is a matrix built
%elsewhere) to find where they are in the coordinates of image 2
im2EstHom = HEst*im1Hom;
im2EstCart = im2EstHom(1:2,:)./repmat(im2EstHom(3,:),2,1);
im2EstCart = round(im2EstCart);

%check if the the transformed position is within the boundary of image 2 
validCoords = im2EstCart(1,:)>0 & im2EstCart(2,:)>0 & im2EstCart(1,:)<=im2width & im2EstCart(2,:)<=im2height;
im1Cart_toupdate=im1Cart(:,validCoords);
im2EstCart_tocopyfrom=im2EstCart(:,validCoords);

%copy colour from image 2 to image 1 - currently pixel by pixel
%but CAN THIS BE VECTORISED?
for i=1:size(im1Cart_toupdate,2)
    im1y=im1Cart_toupdate(1,i);
    im1x=im1Cart_toupdate(2,i);
    im2y=im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(1,i);
    im2x=im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(2,i);
    im1(im1y,im1x,:) = im2(im2y,im2x,:);
    drawnow
end
```

Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

This would be one vectorized approach using [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[m2,n2,r2] = size(im2);
RHS_idx1 = (im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(2,:)-1)*m2 + im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(1,:)
RHS_allidx = bsxfun(@plus,RHS_idx1(:),(0:r2-1)*m2*n2)

[m1,n1,r1] = size(im1);
LHS_idx1 = (im1Cart_toupdate(2,:)-1)*m1 + im1Cart_toupdate(1,:)
LHS_allidx = bsxfun(@plus,LHS_idx1(:),(0:r1-1)*m1*n1)

im1(LHS_allidx) = im2(RHS_allidx)
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another approach that reshapes the input `3D` array to a `2D` array after merging the first two dimensions, then using `linear indexing` for extracting and setting values and finally reshaping back to its original `3D` size, like so -

```
[m2,n2,r2] = size(im2)
RHS_idx1 = (im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(2,:)-1)*m2 + im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(1,:)
im2r = reshape(im2,[],r2) 

[m1,n1,r1] = size(im1)
LHS_idx1 = (im1Cart_toupdate(2,:)-1)*m1 + im1Cart_toupdate(1,:)
im1r = reshape(im1,[],r1)
im1r(LHS_idx1,:) = im2r(RHS_idx1,:)

im1 = reshape(im1r,size(im1));
```

Comment: Many thanks Divakar.  I went with approach 2, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, I made one minor amendment which was to swap the indexing of im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(2,:) to im2EstCart_tocopyfrom(1,:) and similar for im1Cart_topupdate().  This is because these matrices store X coordinates in the first row, Y coordinates in the second, and because the image array im1 and im2 have Y values in the first dimension, X values in the second.   (Although this was not easily evident from the code I posted above).  Thanks again.